# Android - performance issue with ListView update when in Fragment

Tags: android, performance, fragment

I have my layout like following:

> ---
>
> ```
> |       Header                            |
> ___________________________________________
> |               |                          |    
> |               |                          |
> | List of user  | Fragment with Details    |
> |               | [Contains ListView]      |
> |               |                          |
> |               |                          |
> ___________________________________________
>      Footer
> ___________________________________________
> ```

The Header, Footer and ListView of user is in main activity.
  The right side contains a fragment with a list view for the user selected in the listview in left side.

I'm facing performance issue for updating the list view inside fragment. After I click a user, I need to wait for almost 7-8 seconds to see the list getting updating on the right side.

However if I put everything part of same activity, that is even the details ListView in activity and not fragment (And thus removing the fragment usage), then the same responds quite fast. It comes down to 1-1.5 seconds. 
I need to use fragment, as in the detail section I want to show different kinds of information based on some user mode. And each of the corresponding details can be in respective fragment.

With fragment, I tried to figure out where it is taking time. And the time is taking when I do detaillistview.setAdapter or the corresponding adapter.notifyDatasetChanged. There is no time taken for data preparation as I have the corresponding data in memory and only the list needs to be refreshed with the input data.

I tried adding fragment in the xml as well dynamically through code. When did dynamically through code, the xml didnot have fragment but have a placeholder layout area which I use as parent when adding fragment through code. Performance per se it is the similar response.

I would like to know what can I do to improve performance.

thanks
pradeep

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you any advice without seeing the code you use.